# Сириализация WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Помогите! Нужно при нажатии на кнопку сериализовать коллекцию данных. Использовал Newtonsoft, однако из-за свойства Parent появляется циклическая ошибка. Ещё кроме этого не работает команда десериализации файла в котором есть данные.
Код объекта Item:

```
    public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public Item? Parent { get; set; }

    public DateTime timeCreate = DateTime.Now;

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Childs { get; set; }
}
```

Код команд:

```
    public string filePath = "file.json";
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public ICommand SerializeCollectionCommand { get; }

    private bool CanSerializeCollectionCommandExecute(object p) => Items != null;

    private void OnSerializeCollectionCommandExecuted(object p)
    {
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Items);
        File.WriteAllText(filePath, json);
    }

    public ICommand DeserializeCollectionCommand { get; }

    private bool CanDeserializeCollectionCommandExecute(object p) => true;

    private void OnDeserializeCollectionCommandExecuted(object p)
    {
        var json = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Item>>(json);
    }
```

Может есть какие-то альтернативы или можно сделать проще, предложите, а то сам новичок.

Comment: Касательно "цикличности", то наверно [это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18223985/6808809). Касательно MVVM - вы его нарушаете, ибо у вас ViewModel слой вдруг выполняет работу Model слоя, выполняя операцию с данными и файлами.

Comment: Я когда-то делал так https://stackoverflow.com/a/63670028/12888024